# Adding to a string (as numeral) with JS RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, math

Is it possible to add (+1) to a (substring) with regex/replace? For instance, if I have a string (the window location in this case) that ends in `#img-{digit}`, is it possible with regex to replace the digit with what it was `+1`?

I can match the hash like this, but I'm not sure how I can extract the number (which can be more than 2 digits! e.g. `12`).

```
var loc = window.location,
    locstr = loc.match(/#img-\d+/),
    // untested:
    locrep = locstr.replace(/\d/, Number($1) + 1);
```

Let's say that my current hash is `#img-4`, then I want a JS snippet that changes it to `#img-5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [callback in `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var locrep = locstr.replace(/\d+/, function($0) { return Number($0) + 1; });
//=> #img-5
```

Or else:

```
var locrep = locstr.replace(/(#img-)(\d+)/i, 
                           function($0, $1, $2) { return $1 + (Number($2) + 1); });
//=> #img-5
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/goL0t7gs/2/). Console returns `undefined is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the string like #img-{digit}, you can use split with - like this

```
var loc = window.location,
    locstr = loc.split("-");
    var newloc = locstr[0]+parseInt(locstr[1])+1;
```

Comment: I was thought to always use *radix* in `parseInt`, so just sharing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note, `window.location` returns `window.location` `object` ; e.g.,

`console.log(typeof window.location, typeof window.location.hash);`

Try

```
var loc = window.location.hash
, locrep = loc.match(/[^\d]/g).join("") + (1+Number(loc.match(/\d/g).join("")));
```